# Problema de validação de campo

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf-2.2, jpa-2.0

Estou tendo problema de validar os campos de duas entidade

Pedido

```
package com.algaworks.pedidovenda.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido")
public class Pedido implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private Date dataCriacao;
    private String observacao;
    private Date dataEntrega;
    private BigDecimal valorFrete = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal valorDesconto = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal valorTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private StatusPedido status = StatusPedido.ORCAMENTO;
    private FormaPagamento formaPagamento;
    private Usuario vendedor;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private EnderecoEntrega enderecoEntrega;
    private List<ItemPedido> itens = new ArrayList<>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "data_criacao", nullable = false)
    public Date getDataCriacao() {
        return dataCriacao;
    }

    public void setDataCriacao(Date dataCriacao) {
        this.dataCriacao = dataCriacao;
    }

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    public String getObservacao() {
        return observacao;
    }

    public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
        this.observacao = observacao;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "data_entrega", nullable = false)
    public Date getDataEntrega() {
        return dataEntrega;
    }

    public void setDataEntrega(Date dataEntrega) {
        this.dataEntrega = dataEntrega;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "valor_frete", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 2)
    public BigDecimal getValorFrete() {
        return valorFrete;
    }

    public void setValorFrete(BigDecimal valorFrete) {
        this.valorFrete = valorFrete;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "valor_desconto", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 2)
    public BigDecimal getValorDesconto() {
        return valorDesconto;
    }

    public void setValorDesconto(BigDecimal valorDesconto) {
        this.valorDesconto = valorDesconto;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "valor_total", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 2)
    public BigDecimal getValorTotal() {
        return valorTotal;
    }

    public void setValorTotal(BigDecimal valorTotal) {
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    public StatusPedido getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(StatusPedido status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "forma_pagamento", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public FormaPagamento getFormaPagamento() {
        return formaPagamento;
    }

    public void setFormaPagamento(FormaPagamento formaPagamento) {
        this.formaPagamento = formaPagamento;
    }

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vendedor_id", nullable = false)
    public Usuario getVendedor() {
        return vendedor;
    }

    public void setVendedor(Usuario vendedor) {
        this.vendedor = vendedor;
    }

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cliente_id", nullable = false)
    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    @Embedded
    public EnderecoEntrega getEnderecoEntrega() {
        return enderecoEntrega;
    }

    public void setEnderecoEntrega(EnderecoEntrega enderecoEntrega) {
        this.enderecoEntrega = enderecoEntrega;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pedido", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<ItemPedido> getItens() {
        return itens;
    }

    public void setItens(List<ItemPedido> itens) {
        this.itens = itens;
    }

    @Transient
    public boolean isNovo() {
        return getId() == null;
    }

    @Transient
    public boolean isExistente() {
        return !isNovo();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Pedido other = (Pedido) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

EnderecoEntrega

```
package com.algaworks.pedidovenda.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Embeddable
public class EnderecoEntrega implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String logradouro;
    private String numero;
    private String complemento;
    private String cidade;
    private String uf;
    private String cep;

    @NotBlank @Size(max = 150)
    @Column(name = "entrega_logradouro", nullable = false, length = 150)
    public String getLogradouro() {
        return logradouro;
    }

    public void setLogradouro(String logradouro) {
        this.logradouro = logradouro;
    }

    @NotBlank @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "entrega_numero", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    @Size(max = 150)
    @Column(name = "entrega_complemento", length = 150)
    public String getComplemento() {
        return complemento;
    }

    public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
        this.complemento = complemento;
    }

    @NotBlank @Size(max = 60)
    @Column(name = "entrega_cidade", nullable = false, length = 60)
    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    @NotBlank @Size(max = 60)
    @Column(name = "entrega_uf", nullable = false, length = 60)
    public String getUf() {
        return uf;
    }

    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }

    @NotBlank @Size(max = 9)
    @Column(name = "entrega_cep", nullable = false, length = 9)
    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

}
```

Será que existe alguma configuração errada?

Essa é a imagem que aparece

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

era para validar todos os campos.

Answer (score 0):

Não está validando os campos valores porque realmente eles não são nulos, eles estão zerados.
Se quiser validar eles utilize a anotação [`@Min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html).

```
@NotNull
@Min(1) // só aceita long
@Column(name = "valor_frete", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 2)
public BigDecimal getValorFrete() {
    return valorFrete;
}
```

Ou você pode criar uma [validação customizada](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints).

Comment: tenho que usar aonde e como ?

Comment: @wladyband Atualizei.

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de setar os valores campos com 0,00 tenta usar placeholder que ele não reconhece como valor exemplo :

1º Adicione a lib

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
     xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
```

2º Adicione no seu campo no seu caso valor do frete e valor desconto

```
 <p:inputText value="#{valordoCampo}" pt:placeholder="0,00"/>
```